# create NAT Network in Virtualbox - hardware virtualization enabled - cannot disable

Tags: virtualbox, nat

Good morning,

I am encountering some issues when trying to create a NAT Network in virtualbox.

This is the error message that I get (and keep on getting) :

the hardware virtualization is enabled in the Acceleration section of the System page although it is not supported by the host system. It should be disabled in order to start the virtual system

In the acceleration section however, I am not allowed to modify anything, I keep on getting the same message as above. Whatever I choose as an option, the OK-icon never lights up and I cannot confirm any new setting.

I hope you can help me out with this.

Many thanks in advance,

MDK Bellemans

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcjPl.jpg)

Comment: Ps. I have ubuntu 19.10 ...

Answer (score 0):

The above warning message means that you need to enable virtualization technology or VT is enabled from your BIOS, this is different depending on your computer, the usual procedure is:

1. Reboot your computer.
2. Look for instructions (on the bottom of the screen) on how to enter bios settings.
3. In the settings look for VT or hardware virtualization, enable it, save and quit.

If you need more help then google How to enable virtualization on, replace with your computer model.